# Copy artifacts from container to azure artifact

Tags: docker, azure-devops, yaml

I have an image in ACR, I am pulling it and running container on MS hosted ubuntu agent to build an api inside that container

- script: |
  docker pull $(acr_name)/$(image_name):$(label)
  displayName: 'Pull Docker image from ACR'
- script: |
  docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/workspace $(acr_name)/$(image_name):$(label) sh -c " \
  cd /workspace/NFC/api && ls && make && ls"
  displayName: 'Build NFC, Gate, Face apis using Docker image'

after the MAKE command a new file has been generated [image]
I want to add this file to azure artifacts
I tried below things

1. copying file using cp command from current directory to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) but inside container it's not possible
2. I tried sudo docker cp but I'm not able to do it in a new Script task, after docker run command, next task/script won't recognize the container created in previous script